# Use powershell to retrieve Event Forwarding state and configuration

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-event-log

I need to know if the current Windows client has enable Windows Event Fowarding, and where is it forwarding to.

Can I do this with powershell? I couldn't find anything relative on Google, does anyone know?

Comment: Maybe you can use PS to check if the Windows Event Collector service is even running. I think that's essential for Windows Event Forwarding to work.
One you do that, you can probably use Get-eventlog -logname "Forwarded Events" to collect something?

This is purely based on guessing. I don't have this setup at all.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to run the command line `wecutil es` and parse the output in powershell

Here somebody wrote a wrapper for the command line utility to make it easier to consume in your script
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWecutil/0.0.0.3

I couldn't find a WMI query that would list event log subscriptions that are registered, or that would probably be the best way without extensive code

You could also import the C++ functions from the Win32 API into PowerShell and call the API directly to retrieve this information but it would require you to write multiple complex functions